# Why does static member initialization need to be "typed again"?

Tags: c++, class, static, initialization

Here is the case. Static class memmbers must be initialized before using this class, because static members are not object-dependable. They occupy their own place of storage in the heap.
But I am confused about the regulations the initialization has to follow.

The code below explains my concern.

```
class TEST
{
public:
    ...
    static int val;
    ...
}
//Initialization
//int TEST::val = 1;//This is correct.
TEST::val = 1; //This is wrong, compiler msg: lack of type identifier.
//I think that the val member has been declared as int type.
//So WHY must I redeclare its type again? Or I did just miss something?
```

Comment: Why do you need to give the return type of functions in their definitions?

Comment: Maybe `auto TEST::val = 1;` could be a good suggestion for the next standard?! Definitions can deduce the types if a corresponding declaration exists.

Comment: I can only guess that the reason is that there was a desire to align the syntax of definitions of static members with the general syntax of symbol definitions (as opposed to the syntax of mere assignments). It would be confusing if symbol definitions had different syntax depending on whether or not they define predeclared symbols. (For a similar reason I'd find it confusing if `auto` was allowed for this, because `auto` usually means "derive the type from the value", not "derive the type from a previous declaration".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, nothing prevents C++ designers from letting you skip the type in the definition of the `val` member. Indeed, the compiler knows the type already, and the syntax that looks like an assignment is not otherwise valid outside functions, so there is nothing to prevent the compiler from implementing this approach.

However, this would make the parser more complicated, because the same construct (an assignment) would have to be interpreted differently based on the context. In other words, the same line

```
TEST::val = 1;
```

would mean completely different things inside and outside a function. When used inside a function, this line would be treated as an assignment; when used outside a function, the same line would be treated as a definition.

To make life less complicated, both for themselves and the users of the language, the designers decided to stay with the familiar syntax for definitions, at a small expense of asking the users to repeat themselves.

Comment: It seems to me this is speculation; it may be you are on the right track, but I could equally argue that this harks down to how C does it: `extern int const a;` followed by `int const a = 5;` and C++ just added up the class name. Unless you have sources, of course.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The same logic could be applied to `extern`s only at the expense of making it mandatory for an `extern` declaration to be visible at the point in the translation unit where the corresponding `extern` variable is defined (which is currently optional). For static class members, it is required.

Comment: @MatthieuM. How about this logic for the compiler? Is val defined? yes --> assign; No --> definition.

Comment: @richard.g: it is less a matter of what is feasible (more modern languages have much better syntax), and more a matter of what is and how it came to be. Yes, C and C++ could do better; but frankly if I had to reform the languages I would focus less on syntax and more on semantics, *undefined behavior* is a much greater evil.

Answer (score 2):

`static int val` is a declaration (just a type and a name, no memory, no value). A definition 'allocates' storage (may be garbage without a default constructor), an initialization does additionally assign a value. It is the same as with function prototypes and actual definitions.

Comment: I think OP's point was that the compiler already knows that `TEST::val` is an `int` from its declaration, so why doesn't it use this knowledge to let you skip specifying that `int` in a second place. The same question can be asked about function prototypes, though (and it does not have a particularly good answer, either).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : I may not answer the actual question. This is required by design, for simplicity. In a simple editor, I wouldn't want to switch between header and translation unit just to find out what the actual type is either. This way, the header is also less tightly coupled to a translation unit.

Comment: Absolutely - that is why I said that there is no particularly good answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: given that functions can be overloaded, they are widely different.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Not as far as their return type is concerned.